# Initing a NSArray with a method which returns an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c

I have a method that returns an NSArray:

```
-(NSArray *)arrayMethod {
if (x == 2) { return array1; } else { return array2; }
}
```

Can I do something like:

```
NSArray *finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[self arrayMethod]];
```

Thanks already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `arrayWithArray` instead `arrayWithObject`.

```
NSArray *finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self arrayMethod]];
```

OR alternatively

```
NSArray *tempArray = [self arrayMethod];
NSArray *finalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
```

Comment: What do you mean appropriate object?

Comment: @Matoe : `arrayMethod` method should be the part of `self` class.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this instead:

> **arrayWithArray:** Creates and returns an array containing the
>   objects in another given array.
>
> - (id)arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)anArray